# How to make NSManagedObject NSString properties be with "copy" instead of "retain"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

By default when creating NSManagedObject subclass file from data model, Core Data creates properties of type NSString (nonatomic, retain) for string type columns. I might be done due to performance consideration, however, I'm implementing Data Mapper pattern where core data NSManagedObject subclasses are separated from  model classes. So when converting model classes to Core data NSManagedObject subclass, retain just assigns a pointer and not a copy. From the architecture point of view, it brakes logic separation between core data access and model classes, so I need to use copy instead of retain.

Is it the only way to do is manually to change properties in NSManagedObject subclasses?

Comment: Just in case you aren't aware of this - the `copy` method of a normal (non-mutable) `NSString` returns the same instance, so don't freak out your copying property doesn't actually copy anything when you test it.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, already tested. "Copy" copies mutable type objects only. Also, interesting to note, "copy" property also sends copy messages to NSArray elements, so mutable strings will be copied if exist inside array.

Comment: Please, take a look at my comment below the answer. Today, tried to figure out the practical usage "copy" properties. I understand how they work, just never had a need to use NSMutableString, so copy in my experience is redundant and just for future protection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to do this is to change the declaration of the property in an NSManagedObject subclass. Thankfully, Core Data then handles the rest automatically.

Comment: It's very likely some entities will change in core data model schema during development process, so regenerating NSManagedObjects will overwrite edited properties to "retain". So, it's a little inconvenience.

Comment: Also, would like to share my thoughts on "copy" properties. The  properties prevent from changing the value of NSMutableString property from outside. There's no mutable NSNumber and NSDate, so "copy" affects only strings. However, according to my second year of iOS app development, I have never had a need to use NSMutableString, so "copy" case is very rare IMHO :) Apple encourages to use copy on NSString properties in their examples but uses "retain" on arrays, dictionaries and sets, though the same overwrite case exist (see my first comment below the question). Kind of a lack of one rule...

Comment: @centurion try mogenerator. It separates your code into the generated class and a subclass of that; you can edit the subclass without changes being overwritten.